# How is an example path selected in FindShortestPath

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The operation

> FindShortestPath[Gr, 1, 2]]

finds a shortest path in the graph Gr between nodes labelled 1 and 2 (measured in hops).

It just selects some path at random. See the graphic below. The shortest path displayed is composed of 10 hops.

**How? Is it the uniform measure on the set of shortest paths?** Is there perhaps a fast algorithm which selects paths non-uniformly?

[image]

Comment: `FindShortestPath` gives you *one* shortest path.  That's all you can assume about the result, and nothing else, definitely not any uniform distribution.  Perhaps you should read up on some shortest path finding algorithms to have better insight.

Comment: My interpretation was that if a graph had multiple shortest paths, how does `FindShortestPath[]` pick which one to return?

Comment: @J.M. I got that, but it is wrong to assume any principle behind it.  It depends on the type of algorithm used, on the particular implementation of that algorithm, and on how exactly the graph was stored.  The answer is that the function is not intended to give you any guarantees about this whatsoever.  The OP would realize this if he looked at how one might find shortest paths in practice.

Comment: To figure out the literal answer, you would very likely need not only the general method (which is documented and selectable), but the actual C (or whatever language) code used to implement the function.  It would be a futile exercise with no practical result.